# Identifying and adding macros

Tags: macros, formatting

I added two macros:

```
\newcommand{\tblkeyword}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\tblkeyword}[2]{\textcolor{blue}{#2}}
```

and tried to use at like:

```
\tblkeyword{ObjectId} // which shows red color.
```

Issues:

1. I was facing issue in displaying blue color text using macro. That is solved
2. My code contains multiple blocks(schema), similar to code given below. I wanted to know, can I create macro for tabular content. Like for macro `\newcommand\tblcol[2][red]{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}`, I can use `\tblcol{hello}` to define text in `red`. 
   similar way is possible for tabular?

Here is my test: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/539e8676a878ae2d2a29ce14?r=380e068e&rs=ps&rm=d

Code snippet:

```
\begin{document}

\colorbox{black}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep]{\color{white}\textbf {User schema}}}

\[
  \text{Users} \left\{ \begin{tabular}{@{}p{.8\linewidth}@{}}
    \textbf{ID}:  \tblkeyword{ObjectID} -- Id do registro \\
    \textbf{Name}:\tblkeyword{String}-- Name co usuario \\
    \textbf{date}: \tblkeyword{Date} -- Date de Cadastro \\
    \textbf{ren\_date}: \tblkeyword1{Date} -- Data de \\
    \textbf{email}: \parbox[t]{.9\linewidth}{\raggedright\textcolor{red}{String} -- Lorem ipsum dolorsitamet, consecteturadipisicingelit, sed do 
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minimveniam, exercitationullamcolaborisnisi ut 
      aliquipexeacommodoconsequat. Duisautereprehenderit in voluptatevelit esse cillumdolore eu fugiatnullapariatur. Occaecatcupidatat 
      non proident, sunt in culpa quiofficiadeseruntmollit.\strut} \\
    \textbf{accesslog}: \textcolor{red}{Array} \begin{tabular}[t]{@{\ }|l@{}}
      \strut \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
      $\left\{\begin{tabular}{p{.7\linewidth}}
         \textbf{date}: :\tblkeyword{String} Data -- da ocorrncia. \\
         \textbf{user}::\tblkeyword{ObjectId} -- que executou. \\
         \textbf{action}: :\tblkeyword{String}String --  Aço Executada. \\
       \end{tabular}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace$ \\
      $\left\{\begin{tabular}{p{.7\linewidth}}
         \textbf{date}: :\tblkeyword{String} Data -- da ocorrncia. \\
         \textbf{user}: :\tblkeyword{ObjectId}-- que executou. \\
         \textbf{action}: :\tblkeyword{String} -- Aço Executada. \\
       \end{tabular}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace$
    \end{tabular}

    \\
\textcolor{blue} {\hyperlink{page.2}{\textbf {group\_id : }}} \tblkeyword {ObjectId} - Id do  grupo. 

  \end{tabular}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
\]
```

**UPDATE**

By tabular section I mean this section.

[image: schema]

This content is repeated many times in my document. Can i create macro for this?

Comment: Your macros has identical names but different number of arguments (first `[1]`, the second has `[2]` arguments), this will lead to a conflict. You can however use a command with an optional argument or a key-value syntax

Comment: Package `listings` might be of interest to you.

Comment: thanks for advice, but an example will help me. And any suggestion for macro for tabular content?

Comment: It is unclear of what exactly your problem is? As Christian Hupfer said, your two macros are not allowed, either create a command for each color, or do it key based: `\newcommand\tblcol[2][red]{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}` which defaults `\tblcol{hello}` to red color, but `\tblcol[blue]{hello}` will be blue.

Comment: @zeroth: I have multitple tabular content in my code, here I have shown only one. Please check the link. I want to add macro for tabular content. Is that possible?

Comment: @Johannes_B: can you please check see comment

Comment: I am afraid "add macro for tabular content" is too undefined. Could you possibly specify what that problem involves? You can do `\newcommand\tblcon{Hello table}\begin{tabular}{cc}\tblcon&\tblcon\end{tabular}` but I don't think that is your problem? (also, not everybody has a sharelatex account). Remember, we _are_ trying to help you, even though you may feel our comments are ill-placed. As it stands it is just unclear what the problem is. :)

Comment: @zeroth: Sorry I could not clearly state the issue. I am redefining it. Again apologize for private sharelatex link. I have made it public now. please wait a moment, I am rewriting the question

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: dude, can I degine macro for tabular section?

Comment: @cylic: I do understand neither your OP nor your comment really. What do you mean by `tabular section`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: can you please see update? please let me know if still it's not clear

Comment: @cyclic, Still I think it is unclear what you want, do you want _exactly_ the same table shown several places? Its just because that seems counter-intuitive as one could reference said table.

Comment: @zeroth: It's not same table, but similar tables. Actually it's simple table. But it's schema, different schema will be used n different pages with minor change

Comment: You can create whatever macro you want, say: `\newcommand\mytable[2]{\begin{tabular}{cc}#1 & #2 \\ Hello & Hello\end{tabular}}` and then call `\mytable{Head 1}{Head 2}` and `\mytable{Head 3}{Head 4}`. If this is what you want?

Comment: @zeroth: yes, something like that. can you please write answer for this? I guess likewise I can write macros for making text bold `\newcommand{\tblkeyword}[1]{\textbf{#1}}` and also for `hyperlink` i.e. to add link. right?

Comment: Yes, I don't think it will be helpful for others here, I think you should search this forum for "How to use `\newcommand`" and you would be fine. :)